# Nestjs exception in Promise crashes application

Tags: nestjs

In a `nestjs` application if an exception is being throwed in a Promise the whole application crashes.

Is there a workaround?

In the code bellow: calling `getHello` crashes the app so that you have to restart it.

Calling `getHello1` works, we catch the error, but I cannot throw an Exception.
An error is logged and the application is not responding anymore

```js
import { Controller, Get, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    new Promise(function () {
      new URL(''); // throw exception
    });

    return this.appService.getHello();
  }

  @Get('/hello1')
  getHello1(): string {
    new Promise(function () {
      new URL(''); // throw exception
    }).catch((reason) => {
      console.error(reason);
    });

    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

```bash
TypeError: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:564:9)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:640:5)
    at D:\Projects.oe\repos\project-name\src\app.controller.ts:11:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at AppController.getHello (D:\Projects.oe\repos\project-name\src\app.controller.ts:10:5)
    at D:\Projects.oe\repos\project-name\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:38:29
    at InterceptorsConsumer.intercept (D:\Projects.oe\repos\project-name\node_modules\@nestjs\core\interceptors\interceptors-consumer.js:11:20)
    at D:\Projects.oe\repos\project-name\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:60
    at D:\Projects.oe\repos\project-name\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:23
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be because of a floating promise.

Solution:

```js
  async getHello(): Promise<string> {
    await new Promise(() => {
      throw new Error('error');
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('OK');
    });
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
```